# Which git products support pull requests?

Tags: git, github, pull-request, bitbucket-server

Of all of the functions that GitHub supports on top of core Git functionality, pull requests are, I think, the most important.

Which products/projects support pull requests in some form or another?  Obviously GitHub does, and I've read that Atlassian Stash does as well.  Are there others?

Answer (score 1):

[GitLab](http://gitlab.org) also has that feature (they call it Merge requests)